# live url preview not working when url is cloned to textarea

Tags: jquery, url, preview

I'm setting up an Humhub intranet website.

I'm using the [jquery plugin liveurl](https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl) to create a live preview of an url typed in a comment box.

Humhub comments area is an editable div which content is cloned to an hidden textarea.

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" placeholder="write here"></textarea>
<div class="input-area" style="width: 300px; height: 100px; border:1px solid #CCC;" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Humhub uses following jquery to clone the content to the textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                            $('.input-area').keyup(function () {
                                if ($(this).html() == "" || $(this).html() == " " || $(this).html() == " <br>") {
                                        $(this).html(placeholder);
                                        $(this).addClass('atwho-placeholder');
                                } else {
                                        $('textarea').val(getPlainInput($(this).clone()));



                                }
                        })
```

When entering an url in the div.input-area, it is cloned to the textarea but liveurl plugin does nothing. The code I've got from the liveurl plugin site is the following.

```
$('textarea').liveUrl({
                            loadStart : function(){
                                    console.log('start');
                            },
                            loadEnd : function(){
                                    console.log('finished');
                            },
                            success : function(data) 
                            {  
                                console.log(data);
                                // this return the first found url data
                            }
                        });
```

When I enter the url direct in the textarea the succes function is executed correctly and the data attr contains the correct information.

Could someone help me or has someone an other solution to create a live url preview??

Comment: This will be down to events. When pasting into the DIV, its not triggering the required event on the textarea.

Comment: thnx! I can't trigger the liveurl event on the div.input-area because it only supports textarea's...

Answer (score 3):

jquery liveurl expects a keyup event to be triggered on the textarea. Cloning content from contenteditable div to textarea will just copy the content but not trigger keyup. You can try triggering keyup after cloning.
[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srikpreethy/5g5qubnk/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input-area').keyup(function () {
            $('textarea').val($('.input-area').html()).trigger('keyup');

    })
});
```